# C#: Is there any way to "trim" a function to fit into a delegate by specifying the values of extra arguments?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm working on a project that frequently passes functions as parameters via delegates.
Example:

```
delegate double MathFunction(double x);
void render_function(double x0, double x1, double x_interval, MathFunction f)
{...}
```

A common situation I run into is wanting to pass a function in that has additional arguments, which I want to have a constant value each time it is called within render_function. But I don't want to just remove the arguments and replace them with constants because I am calling render_function multiple times with different values for those arguments.

Example of what I'd like to do:

```
double sin_wave(double x, double frequency, double magnitude) {...}

render_function(x0, x1, x_interval, sin_wave(frequency: 3, magnitude: 0.5));
render_function(x0, x1, x_interval, sin_wave(frequency: 2, magnitude: 1.5));
```

A couple solutions have crossed my mind:

- build an argument array system such as using params
- wrap the functions that need extra arguments inside of an object, use the object's state to control the extra arguments' values.

But these both seem inelegant to me. Any cleaner solutions out there?

Comment: [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

Comment: [Named and Optional Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: @RobertHarvey you'll notice that these are both technologies that I mentioned in my question. Can you elaborate on how you would use these to address the problem?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Didn't see any mention of the `params` keyword or optional arguments.  Come to think of it, I still don't.  Perhaps you can be a little clearer why neither of these solutions works for you?

Comment: I've edited to clarify where params would fit in. It is a system for passing arrays of arguments. But of course it is more convenient than if I had to build my own.
I use named arguments in my 2nd code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it in a lambda:

```
render_function(x0, x1, x_interval, x => sin_wave(x, frequency: 3, magnitude: 0.5));
```

Comment: Oh, that is a neat use of lambda, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing everything by hand, the straight forward way would involve defining a class instance to hold the cached arguments and call the method for you;

```cs
public class Sin {
    private readonly double frequency;
    private readonly double magnitude;
    public Sin(double frequency, double magnitude) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.magnitude = magnitude; 
    }
    public double Call(double x) => sin_wave(x, frequency, magnitude);
}
MathFunction func = new Sin(3, ...).Call;
```

But you can make the C# compiler build something equivalent to the above for you;

```cs
MathFunction func = Sin(double frequency, double magnitude)
    => (x) => sin_wave(x, frequency, magnitude);
```

Or just build the delegate directly;

```cs
MathFunction func = (x) => sin_wave(x, 3, 0.5);
```